# How to avoid "RewriteBase"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do not want to manually set `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` of every site. How can I set it relative, so moving site root to a new location does not require any modification in it.

I already read this  http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/avoiding_rewritebase_with_mod_rewrite.php but it seems to not be applicable in .htaccess files. Here is an example `htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why do you need RewriteBase in the first place?

Comment: You need mod_rewrite for pretty URLs, but why do you need to set RewriteBase? Can you show an example?

Comment: Could you post your existing htaccess code so we can see if it's possible to rewrite it without using RewriteBase, please?

Comment: @PHPst: As I wrote in my answer too that creating a symlink is probably easier workaround for you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid modifying RewriteBase in different setups is to use **symlinks to create same name linked directory** every where. And make sure you have this option set at the top:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Thanks, I do not get the point. What this means:"symlinks to create same name linked directory". Should I wipe out `RewriteEngine On` totally after adding that option? Should I use a special directory structure?

Comment: @PHPst: No you don't need to remove `RewriteEngine` line. By symlink I meant this command in `*nix`: `ln -s mysite site1` where `site1` is actual directory where you have all your site files. Now mysite will be a symbolically linked to the `site1` folder. Then inside `site1/.htaccess` you can use `RewriteBase mysite`. On another site you can create another symlink using `ln -s mysite site1` and **there will be no need to change anything inside .htaccess**.